# What is the use of the return value of Files.createDirectory

Tags: java

The signature of [`Files.createDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) is

```
public static Path createDirectory(Path dir, FileAttribute<?>... attrs) IOException
```

And the documentation says this

> Parameters:
>
> - `dir` - the directory to create
> - `attrs` - an optional list of file attributes to set atomically when creating the directory
>
> Returns:
>
> - the directory

Is this just to allow method chaining, or is there something more into it? For example, in this code

```
Path directory = Paths.get("./results");
Path created = Path.createDirectory(directory);
```

should we use `directory` or `created`?

I've checked the source code of the [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/nio/file/Files.java#l671) and it returns the argument, but is it guaranteed by the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to the [Java 8 OCP Guide](https://www.amazon.com.br/OCP-Certified-Professional-Programmer-1Z0-809/dp/1119067901?tag=goog0ef-20&smid=A1ZZFT5FULY4LN&ascsubtag=go_1494986073_58431735035_285514469186_pla-485032980911_c_) (pg 462), method chaining is the purpose of this strategy:

> Many of the methods in the Path interface transform the path value in
>   some way and return a new Path object, allowing the methods to be
>   chained.